# Spring Boot 2.0 Quartz - Use non-primary datasource

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I used Quartz as scheduler in my application. Trying to use Spring boot 2.0 features. I have 2 different data sources in the configuration. One for application and another one for scheduler. How can I use non-primary data source (schedulerDataSource in this case) as data source for Quartz? Please help.

***pom.xml***

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>wlthint3client</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Oracle/products/mw_home/wlserver/server/lib/wlthint3client.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Oracle/products/mw_home/oracle_common/modules/oracle.jdbc/ojdbc7.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
```

***application.yml***

```
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceName: ETL
          threadPool:
            threadCount: 50
          jobStore:
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
            tablePrefix: QRTZ_ 
            useProperties: true

scheduler:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXX)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX)))
    username: scheduler
    password: XXXXXX
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

t3:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXX)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXXXXX)))
    username: app
    password: XXXXXX
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

***AppDataSource.java***

```
@Configuration
public class AppDataSource 
{
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("t3.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties t3DataSourceProperties() 
    {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("t3.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource t3DataSource() 
    {
        return t3DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("scheduler.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties schedulerDataSourceProperties() 
    {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("scheduler.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource schedulerDataSource() 
    {
        return schedulerDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager schedulerTransactionManager()
    {
        final DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(schedulerDataSource());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

***Application.java***

```
package com.aaa.t3.starter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.spdji.aaa.jms.JmsService;

@ComponentScan("com.aaa.t3")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class, JmxAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        JmsService jmsService = (JmsService) context.getBean("jmsService");
        jmsService.sendMessage();

        /*String[] beans = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.stream(beans).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);*/
    }
}
```

Tried to modify data source using SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer, but still it refers primary data source.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig 
{
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public SchedulerConfig(@Qualifier("schedulerDataSource") DataSource dataSource) 
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer schedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer() 
    {
        return bean -> bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Verified using debugger. Autowired data source in SchedulerConfig is scheduler data source, but it has been overridden after that. Added break point in QuartzAutoConfiguration.quartzDataSourceInitializer and checked the data source. This is not scheduler data source. This has been overridden by primary data source. Quartz auto configuration overrides SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer customization. I have opened [github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12780](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12780) to fix it.

This is a bug in spring-boot. As a workaround, I removed spring.quartz.job-store-type property and then configured DataSource and PlatformTransactionManager in customizer. Refer below updated code:

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig 
{
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    public SchedulerConfig(@Qualifier("schedulerDataSource") DataSource dataSource, @Qualifier("schedulerTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) 
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer schedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer() 
    {
        return bean -> 
        {
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            bean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Add qualifier to non primary datasource

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12755 to see if we can make this easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in spring-boot. As a workaround, I removed spring.quartz.job-store-type property and then configured DataSource and PlatformTransactionManager in customizer. Refer below updated code:

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig 
{
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    public SchedulerConfig(@Qualifier("schedulerDataSource") DataSource dataSource, @Qualifier("schedulerTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) 
    {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer schedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer() 
    {
        return bean -> 
        {
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            bean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could customise the datasource by building the `SchedulerFactoryBean` yourself:

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean bean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(schedulerDataSource());
    return bean;
}
```

Or, in Spring Boot 2, you can use a `SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer`. This will allow you customise the bean instantiated by the autoconfigurer, which may be less work.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public SchedulerConfig(@Qualifier("scheduler.datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer schedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer()
    {
        return bean -> bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in configuration instead of building SchedulerFactoryBean?

Comment: Possibly. The javadoc on `SchedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource()` implies that it can be set up in _quartz.properties_, but this is "the Spring way".

Comment: Can I use SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer to assign non-primary data source? I don't want to build new SchedulerFactoryBean since I have to write all boiler plate code.

Comment: teppic - I have added sample code with SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer. Can you take a look and tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @user1020455: The customiser looks to have arrived with spring boot 2 (I've been using 1.5). I tried it out and it "works for me". You shouldn't have to go through the `ApplicationContext` to get the datasource, just Autowire it and reference it directly.

Comment: Modified the code as per your comments, refer original post. It still refers primary data source. Only scheduler data source has Quartz tables and app data source doesn't have it. Even after this change, I am getting exception saying table or view doesn't exist. Please help.

Comment: Try taking the quartz config out of your application.yml.

Comment: Also, check the `dataSource` in your `SchedulerConfig` with a debugger to see if it is the primary or secondary.

Comment: Verified using debugger. Autowired data source in SchedulerConfig is scheduler data source, but looks like it has been overridden after that. Added break point in QuartzAutoConfiguration.quartzDataSourceInitializer and checked the data source. This is not scheduler data source. This has been overridden by primary data source.

Comment: Is it working for you when you use SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer @teppic?

Comment: Yes, it's working with the `SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer`.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
```

and customize the scheduler instance as following:

```
@Bean("qzDataSource")
@Qualifier("qzDataSource")
public HikariDataSource qzDataSource() {
    return qzDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager quartzDataSourceTransactionManager(@Qualifier("qzDataSource") DataSource qzDataSource) {
    final DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(qzDataSource);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory(@Qualifier("qzDataSource") DataSource qzDataSource) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean bean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(qzDataSource);
    bean.setTransactionManager(quartzDataSourceTransactionManager(qzDataSource));
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public Scheduler scheduler() {
    return schedulerFactory(qzDataSource()).getScheduler();
}
```

My full code is https://github.com/guzhangyu/learn-spring-cloud/tree/master/springboot-quartz