# Unable to retrieve quartz job in springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

I am able to create a quartz job in spring but that is about the only thing I can do.  The job does not fire and I can check that the job exists but am unable to retrieve it.

I am using springboot 2.6.6.  My configuration looks like this:

```
spring:
  ################################
  # application properties
  ################################
  application:
    name: job-manager
  ################################
  # postgress database
  ################################
  datasource:
    url: ${db.url}
    username: ${db.username}
    password: ${db.password}
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        ddl-auto: validate
        #format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
    ################################
    # Quartz configuration
    ################################
  quartz:
    auto-startup: false
    job-store-type: jdbc 
    wait-for-jobs-to-complete-on-shutdown: true
    jdbc.initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 5   # each thread runs a concurrent job
org:
  quartz:
    jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

I am able to create a new job and its trigger but the trigger never fires.  I can also execute the following without any problem and it returns true:

```
scheduler.checkExists(new JobKey(jobName, jobGroupName));
```

The above snippet returns true.  However when I try to execute

```
jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(new JobKey(jobName, jobGroupName));
```

I get the following error:

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job: Bad value for type long : \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
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1401) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$9.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1382) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
```

The nested exception is

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \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
```

Any ideas.  I have found one similar post without an answer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to step through and can see that the error is generated while trying to retrieve job_data which is a blob.  I have tried to create a job with empty job_data map, with a null job_data map and with a job_data may of a dummy string as key and value, all resulting in the same error.  I went as far as StdJDBCDelegate::3190.  By the way I am using Quartz 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is configuration '`org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass`' is not correctly picking up '`org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate`'.
As per your exception, Delegate class is still  the default implementation of '`org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate`'

There seems to be error with yaml configuration, refer  here : [Spring Boot Quartz Scheduler Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234224/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-configuration)

Comment: You were absolutely correct.  I needed to place all org.... properties under the properties tag.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.